# How to get date in a given format?

Tags: java, java-8

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Take today's date (say 2021-07-07)
2. Format it as (2021-07-07T00:00:00.000Z)
3. Send it in an API

I am not able to find an easy way to convert `2021-07-07` to `2021-07-07T00:00:00.000Z`. We can of course append `T00:00:00.000Z` string, but I want to avoid that.

Every method I have so far (using LocalDate, LocalDateTime, Instant, Date) involves some use of timezone (ZoneId) or conversion to Epoch and they end up giving response only till seconds and not till milliseconds.

I am sure there must be a simpler way.

**Edit 1:** Passing a Zone Id is not an issue, we can do that.

Comment: What did your search turn up?

Comment: Your API expects ISO 8601 format. According to the ISO 8601 standard seconds and fraction of second are optional. So by all likelihood you can easily get away with sending `2021-07-07T00:00:00Z` or even `2021-07-07T00:00Z`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I tried that, but the API expects data in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` format. This format returns in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, @bob. That’s strict. Then it’s good that the answer shows how to obtain that exact format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need

```
LocalDate.now()
    .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH))
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            LocalDate.now()
                .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH))
        );
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LWyv56)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` would also work well

Comment: @Aaron - `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` will not print the millisecond part which the OP wanted.